# Magento Sub Pages Shows 404 NOT FOUND Error

Tags: php, apache, magento, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I am using **Magento 1.9.1**. I installed Magento successfully in my server. But when I navigate any subpages (example:About Us, Contact Us, Login etc) in front end it shows **404 Not Found** Error. But Home page display correctly.

My `home` page url is something like `this: http://mydomain.in/store` .This display ok. My `Contact Us` page is : `http://mydomain.in/store/contacts` . This shows **Not Found Error.** But when I type url manually like this `http://mydomain.in/store/index.php/contacts` .This shows working. That is when adding `index.php` it became working.

**How can I make this working??**

**Solutions I found:** `Change 'Use Web Server Rewrites' to NO in System->Configuration->Web->Search Engine Optimization.`

This make working, but the url contain `index.php` like this `http://mydomain.in/store/index.php/contacts.` I think `http://mydomain.in/store/contacts` is standard and this should work(but I don't know how). Another issue is `User Logging, checkout etc` are not working here. To make working we can add `form key` in corresponding pages. But this is not preferable because many pages have to change.

**Another solution is**: `make enable apache mod rewrite. Uncomment this line LoadModule 'rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so' inside 'wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf'.`

My question is **How to avoid 404 NOT FOUND ERROR in Magento Subpages?**
When I follow the above solutions the url path contain index.php. And the logging like features become not working.

**How can I avoid index.php in url?**

My folder structure is `D:\wamp\apache2\htdocs\site\store`. **store** folder contain `magento files.`
The `home page` is available in `http://mydomain.in/store.`

Please help me .Any help is really appreciable..

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid index.php in urls you must have `mod_rewrite` enabled on your server and from the Magento admin panel go to `System->conguration->web->Search Engines Optimization` and set the flag `Use Web Server Rewrites` to `Yes`. Clear the cache and give it a go.

Comment: OK, but now login is not working...In my question I already pointed this.

Comment: Use Web Server Rewrites to Yes =>login issue &  Use Web Server Rewrites to No=>Not found error. This is the issue.